# Outlook 2010 Addin - change phrase to link without altering email body

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I've created simple addin for Outlook 2010 that replace specific phrase with link, for example I want to replace `ABC12345` with `http://www.example.com?id=123456`

I'm using this code:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    inspectors = this.Application.Inspectors;
    inspectors.NewInspector += new Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(Inspectors_NewInspector);
}

void Inspectors_NewInspector(Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
{
    var mailItem = Inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
    if (mailItem != null)
    {
        if (mailItem.EntryID != null)
        {
            string pattern = @"ABC(?<number>\d{1,6})";

            var match = Regex.Match(mailItem.HTMLBody, pattern);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                var replaced = Regex.Replace(mailItem.HTMLBody, pattern, m => "<a href=\"http://example.com?query=" + m.Groups["number"].Value+"\">ABC"+ m.Groups["number"].Value+"</a>");
                mailItem.HTMLBody = replaced;
            }      
        }
    }
}
```

However I have two issues:

1. I must double click email in mailbox to have my event fired. I want to display that link when previewing emails (moving up and down in mailbox)
2. My code is replacing content, so Outlook "thinks" I've made some changes and when I want to close window it asks if I want to save those changes.

I don't want to alter body of email, I want to change phrase `ABC123456` into link.

**EDIT1:**

I've tried using `ActiveExplorer`, this allows me to access email in preview window, but when I change email body those changes are saved. My intention is to change how specific text is displayed (change it to link), but not to alter email body on serwer.
I want those changes to be visible in my instance of Outlook, not saved on server (`mailItem.HTMLBody.Replace` does that).
Can I access view that displays email and alter that view?

This is the code:

```
Outlook.Explorer currentExplorer;

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    currentExplorer = this.Application.ActiveExplorer();
    currentExplorer.SelectionChange += new Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_SelectionChangeEventHandler(CurrentExplorer_Event);
}

private void CurrentExplorer_Event()
{
    var selectedFolder =  this.Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder;
    try
    {
        if (this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Count > 0)
        {
            var selObject = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
            if (selObject is Outlook.MailItem)
            {
                Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (selObject as Outlook.MailItem);

                mailItem.HTMLBody = mailItem.HTMLBody.Replace("ABC", "DEF");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

**EDIT2**
I'm able to get WordEditor inside Outlook, but I can't add hyperlink.
Last think I want now is to find specific phrases in email and add hyperlink to them. Here is my current code:

```
Outlook.Explorer currentExplorer;

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    currentExplorer = this.Application.ActiveExplorer();
    currentExplorer.SelectionChange += new Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_SelectionChangeEventHandler(CurrentExplorer_Event);
}

private void CurrentExplorer_Event()
{
    var selectedFolder =  this.Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder;
    try
    {
        if (this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Count > 0)
        {
            var selectedObject = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
            if (selectedObject is Outlook.MailItem)
            {
                var mail = (selectedObject as Outlook.MailItem);
                var inspector = mail.GetInspector;

                if (inspector.IsWordMail())
                {
                    var document = (Document)inspector.WordEditor;

                    if (document != null)
                    {
                        var app = document.Application;
                        var find = document.Range().Find;

                        find.Text = "ABC";
                        while (find.Execute())
                        {
                            var rng = find.Parent as Range;
                            rng.Hyperlinks.Add(rng, "http://example.com/?query=" + rng.Text );
                            rng.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you need. This line mailItem.HTMLBody = replaced; seems to be doing what you say you don't want done. What do you want to do with "replaced"?

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea I want to "change" text `ABC123456` into link. I was trying to replace email body, but this way Outlook thinks I'm editing email. I want to leave email untouched, but I want that text to be link. Hope this make sense :)

Comment: Well, leave the text as link for whom? I'm confused. It sounds an awful lot like you are trying to change the email body :) Do you mean to the person to whom the message is displayed? Also, unrelated, why? - this sounds malicious  :)

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea when I think about it it may sound malicious :) In my work we have very old help desk system that is sending tasks number inside email notifications instead links, this is blackbox for me and (sadly) I can't change that template. Because we are using Outlook 2000+ I thought I can create addin that will change that static text into clickable link. This is my main intention. If You think it is malicious then I'm sorry, but this wasn't my intention.

Comment: More simply, the requirement seems to be to silently change the email body without Outlook noticing.

Comment: @peeebeee this sounds malicious, but Yes. I want to turn specific phrases into links. I'm able to get WordEditor that is inside Outlook, and not I'm trying to add hyperlink to specific text. I'll update my question with partial solution